# C# Combinations of integers

Tags: c#, .net, integer, permutation, combinations

i want to pick the integer **combinations** using a single integer,
like I have a number `1234`.. Now what i want is: `1,2,3,4,12,23,34,123,234,1234`

Kindly help..??

Comment: This looks like all substrings of "1234".

Comment: have to iterate from left to right,, and only using consecutive digits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want all substrings of a given string (in this case the number 1234). So, for a string of length *n* there are *n* substrings of length 1, *n* − 1 substrings of length 2, etc. until one substring of length *n*.

Given that you can easily solve this with two nested loops, e.g.:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Foo(int x) {
  string s = x.ToString();
  for (int length = 1; length <= s.Length; length++) {
    for (int i = 0; i + length < s.Length; i++) {
      yield return int.Parse(s.Substring(i, length));
    }
  }
}
```

(Untested and there are likely fencepost errors, but you get the idea.)

Comment: Yeah,, seems useful... let me think

Answer (score 0):

How about this article on [Permutations, Combinations, and Variations using C# Generics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G)

where permutations and combination are discussed, with code.

Comment: sorry, Hassan, I misunderstood your question. Brilliant article though :) I'm working through it for fun now...

Comment: Thanks... @Joey Solved it though.. :)